# UFT scripts are running on edge browser but unable to identify new objects

Tags: microsoft-edge, hp-uft

The existing scripts which are available was created in internet explorer and now working fine in edge browser. But I can not identify new objects on edge using UFT. How to identify objects on edge?
Note: I am using version 15.0.1.1068 of UFT and edge is IE7 compatible

Comment: It looks like you are using IE 7 document mode to try to be compatible with UFT scripts? Did you try using IE 11 mode instead of IE 7? This might work for you.